# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: object, undefined

Hello i have a problem with my script i recently upgrading all scripts to php 7 and i'm almost done but i cant solve this error.....

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /mnt/web121/d2/33/58167933/htdocs/includes/functions.php on line 201

Could some one help me out with this one ?

```
$drop =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM casinos");

while($tard=mysqli_fetch_object($drop)){
    $per = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$tard->owner'"));
    if ($per->status == "Dead" or $per->status or "Banned"){
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE casinos SET owner='0' WHERE casino='$tard->casino' AND owner='$tard->owner'");
    }

}
```

This is line 201:

```
 if ($per->status == "Dead" or $per->status or "Banned"){
```

Comment: There is no error message here.

Comment: sorry here it is: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /mnt/web121/d2/33/58167933/htdocs/includes/functions.php on line 201

Comment: Full of mistakes... SQL injection, using string like a variable, using `or` instead of `==`. I recommend you reading your book again.

Comment: I have runned this script 10 years ago then it was running fine, perfect no but it is a start the last thing status or banned should be == offcourse my mistake.

Comment: How should i doing this? in the past i learned things to look for a example in a other script and from there i build everything.

If i solve this problem then i have all the information i need to change all my scripts could you fix this error for me ?

Comment: Please show your SQL database schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
$drop = $con->query("SELECT owner FROM casinos");
while ($tard = $drop->fetch_row()) {
    $con->prepare("SELECT status,casino,owner FROM users WHERE username=?")
         ->bind_param("s", $tard[0])->execute()
         ->bind_result($status, $casino, $owner)->fetch()->close();
    if (in_array($status, ["Dead", "Banned"], true)) {
         $con->prepare("UPDATE casinos SET OWNER='0' WHERE casino=? and owner=?")
             ->bind_param("ss", $casino, $owner)->execute();
    }
}
```

Please double check your SQL field name.

Comment: Thanks i will modify it in a sec  what doest bind_param "s" do ? and bind_param "ss" ?

Comment: bind_param is an effective way to avoid SQL injection. "s" means one string, "ss" means two.

Comment: And again many thanks for helping me out.

What i dont understand is that in my script there are many rules like: SELECT * FROM users

What does the * stand for ? you replaced it with owner but how can i find out where the * stands for ?

Comment: i Changed to this:

$drop = $con->query("SELECT * FROM casinos");
while ($tard = $drop->fetch_row()) {
    $con->prepare("SELECT status,casino,owner FROM users WHERE username=$tard->owner")
         ->bind_param("s", $tard[0])->execute()
         ->bind_result($status, $casino, $owner)->fetch()->close();
    if (in_array($status, ["Dead", "Banned"], true)) {
         $con->prepare("UPDATE casinos SET OWNER='0' WHERE casino=$tard->casino and owner=$tard->owner")
             ->bind_param("ss", $casino, $owner)->execute();
    }
}

Comment: Do not do a wildcard query in production. The code is tightly connected to the field ordering, which is the way I access the row with array indexing.

Comment: Oke what shall i use then as alternative ?


I'm getting an error:
Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /mnt/web121/d2/33/58167933/htdocs/includes/functions.php:200 Stack trace: #0 /mnt/web121/d2/33/58167933/htdocs/updates.php(4): include() #1 /mnt/web121/d2/33/58167933/htdocs/main.php(2): include('/mnt/web121/d2/...') #2 {main} thrown in /mnt/web121/d2/33/58167933/htdocs/includes/functions.php on line 200 



from this rule:
 ->bind_param("s", $tard[0])->execute()